# Can't read variables from application.properties

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-kinesis

I am making a Spring application in which I'm sending data to kinesis. I have the `accessKey` and `secretKey` stored in application.properties. In the service implementation class I am using these variables but im getting an error that access key cannot be null.
The ProducerServiceImpl class:

```
public class ProducerServiceImpl extends ProducerService {

private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProducerServiceImpl.class);

@Value(value = "${aws.stream_name}")
private String streamName;

@Value(value = "${aws.region}")
private String awsRegion;

@Value(value = "${aws.access_key}")
private String awsAccessKey;

@Value(value = "${aws.secret_key}")
private String awsSecretKey;

private KinesisProducer kinesisProducer = null;
public ProducerServiceImpl() {
    this.kinesisProducer = getKinesisProducer();
}

private KinesisProducer getKinesisProducer() {
    if (kinesisProducer == null) {

        BasicAWSCredentials awsCreds = new BasicAWSCredentials(awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey);

        KinesisProducerConfiguration config = new KinesisProducerConfiguration();
        config.setRegion(awsRegion);
        config.setCredentialsProvider(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCreds));
        config.setMaxConnections(1);
        config.setRequestTimeout(6000); // 6 seconds
        config.setRecordMaxBufferedTime(5000); // 5 seconds

        kinesisProducer = new KinesisProducer(config);
    }

    return kinesisProducer;
}
```

I think the reason is that because after the function, the constructor is called first, the variables are not being assigned the value from @Value.

Comment: You are doing a constructor for the class, therefore it will not inject the values you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the `@Value` annotation on fields, Spring will use **field injection**. This means that it first needs to create an instance of `ProducerServiceImpl` (by calling your constructor), and then it will use reflection to initialize those fields annotated with `@Value`.

So, since your constructor is invoked **before** the values are injected, they will be `null`.

There are two basic solutions, one is to use constructor injection:

```java
public class ProducerServiceImpl extends ProducerService {
    // ... Fields

    // Pass @Value as constructor parameters
    public ProducerServiceImpl(@Value(value = "${aws.access_key}") String awsAccessKey) {
        // Set the fields before calling getKinesisProducer()
        // If you only need the fields to create the producer, you could also just pass them as arguments to the getKinesisProducer() function
        this.awsAccessKey = awsAccessKey;
        this.kinesisProducer = getKinesisProducer();
    }

    // ...
}
```

The other solution is to wait until Spring has initialized the bean. This can be done by moving the logic to a method annotated with `@PostConstruct`:

```java
public class ProducerServiceImpl extends ProducerService {
    // ... Fields

    // Replace the constructor by a method annotated with @PostConstruct
    @PostConstruct
    public void initializeKinesisProducer() {
        this.kinesisProducer = getKinesisProducer();
    }

    // ...
}
```

---

However, the prefered solution is to move the entire `KinesisProducer` setup to a Spring configuration class, and provide it as a bean. Since all Spring beans are singletons, you can get rid of that initialization code. For example:

```java
// Create a new @Configuration class
@Configuration
public class KinesisConfiguration {

    // Create a @Bean method to construct your KinesisProducer
    @Bean
    // Pass all @Value's as parameters
    public KinesisProducer kinesisProducer(@Value("${aws.access_key} String awsAccessKey) {
        BasicAWSCredentials awsCreds = new BasicAWSCredentials(awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey);         KinesisProducerConfiguration config = new KinesisProducerConfiguration();
        config.setRegion(awsRegion);
        config.setCredentialsProvider(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCreds));
        config.setMaxConnections(1);
        config.setRequestTimeout(6000); // 6 seconds
        config.setRecordMaxBufferedTime(5000); // 5 seconds

        return new KinesisProducer(config);
    }
}
```

Now you can delete all that code in your service and use:

```java
public class ProducerServiceImpl extends ProducerService { 
    // Inject your KinesisProducer, either through field injection or constructor injection
    @Autowired
    private KinesisProducer kinesisProducer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest moving your `@Value` configuration properties to another class using `@ConfigurationProperties` and inject that in your constructor.